# WordPress plugin Content is not showing in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Hello I am working with WordPress and I used the **Frontpage News Plugin** It is

working fine on the Firefox and Google Chrome. it is showing the right side

Latest news [link](https://manresa-sj.com/)

[image]

But is not showing the Latest News in Internet Explorert

[image]

**I am using IE version 10**. How to fix this problem

Comment: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">

Comment: where put this tag ?means put into the header?

Comment: in header.php file in your theme

Answer (score 1):

**Basic Issue with browser**

- Clearing WordPress.com Cookies
- Check that JavaScript is enabled

http://enable-javascript.com/

- If you are still having trouble, here are a few more things you can try:
- Upgrade your browser and Flash Player to the latest version available.
- Make sure wordpress.com, wp.com and their subdomains (*.wordpress.com / *.wp.com) are not blocked by your browser. This also applies to your firewall or anti-virus software settings if you have any.

**Some That I found :**

Is there line called in your header.php:

```
<?php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes();?>>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset' );?>">

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

wp_head();?>
</head>
```

**Complete Article Here:**

http://2slick.com/web/wordpress-problem-with-ie9internet-explorer-9/tutorials

**Updated**

CSS display issue. content rendering div is not worked as you need.

Comment: @ vasim yes this line of code is available and one more thing Latest news content is showing when i  developer tool into IE                      https://manresa-sj.com/

Comment: I just check i compelete display in my IE

Comment: Please check widget  widget widget_wpcufpn_widget

Comment: http://kb.infobridge.com/hc/en-us/articles/203198132-How-to-solve-Widgets-not-displaying-correctly-in-Internet-Explorer

Comment: Mean latest news content  showing your IE on right sidebar

Comment: My browser is upgraded to latest version. 11.0

Comment: how did you find??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130088/discussion-between-shahzad-ditro-and-vasim-vanzara).

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved using CSS. Actually Plugin was working fine content is coming

When  I checked the Developer Tool of the IE.But that was not showing on IE. I

remove the class of a div in which all content was coming then all data is

showing. so when I saw CSS of a removed  class that using the

```
height: auto;
```

which I customized that was conflicting because height is already used by plugin.so I comment the height:auto. that is working fine for me.